# I try to retrieve blob data from db and export it as a file, but the blob object is always lost passing it from ejb tier to action tier

Tags: hibernate, struts, ejb, blob

I have a blob field in the db.

i am using hibernate to extract the data to an entity object, when the data is passed into the dao tier, the blob is there, but when it passed from ejb tier to the struts action tier, the blob become null, seems it is lost somewhere in between, below is the detail context:

1. hibernate entity mapping file,  the blob property is of `java.sql.Blob` type
2. the entity class property is serializableBlob type
3. ejb bean calls dao, and pass the data back to action class, dao retrives the blob object successfully, but when passed back to action, it is lost.

the error information is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Blobs may not be accessed after serialization
```

What are the possible reasons for this?

Answer (score 2):

this has been a problem for me before.

Try to do it in the way mentioned in this blog and it may help
http://hansonchar.blogspot.com/2005/06/oracle-blob-mapped-to-byte-in.html

Comment: @Quincy The links are not working. Can you please update them or help me out with what the solution for this is? Thanks in advance!